# We need to separate translation for users, question counts with scale

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, russian-stackoverflow

As far as I see currently there is no special case in translation for users and question counts with `k` suffix:

> [image: tag-tooltip]

Do not pay attention about `440` in the picture above, we don't have any tags with more than 1k followers, but these times are coming (look for [`[javascript]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)  tag).

For now only "views" and "votes" have special form [with `k` suffix](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/91391915?key=WithScale):

> [image]

We need same behavior for "followers" and "questions" from tag tooltip.
Please add these variants for localization into Transifex.

Comment: I don't have the code in front of me, but I'm pretty sure this should just be a matter of tweaking the way this string is formatted in our code since the ability to vary translations based on the actual number rather than the shortened version already exists.

Comment: Removed a dozen or so irrelevant comments; please, if you're gonna comment on this stuff, be like Adam and try to have at least a vague inkling of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was fixed in  rev `2018.1.11.28366`. The new string are on transifex:

- [0935eeb392f7ae2a443efa6e8355ff7c](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/131573381?key=132ebd405c36bcd836f561600fcc1468)
- [132ebd405c36bcd836f561600fcc1468](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/131578783?key=0935eeb392f7ae2a443efa6e8355ff7c)

The old strings are still used for non-abbreviated counts. The new strings are used only for abbreviated value. Note that they have a `REFERS TO:CountAbbreviated` info on them:

[image]

Comment: Could you please force transfering current version of the Transfex DB into build? I have just made a translations, and we are waiting for transifex.push and site.rebuild.