# Unable to pluralize "awarded" on the badges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, localization, plurals

The word "awarded" on the [Badges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) doesn't have plural versions, hence we're unable to localize it properly.

> [image: awarder]

There also should be a separate version for the kilo-suffexed numbers.

[Current version](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266659?key=87e8bcb1c1d6264d54bcbe34371c92b5) has only single form in the Transifex DB.

Related question on ruSO.meta: [Как перевести "количество раз когда знак был присвоен"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3175/176217)

Comment: I'm still puzzled by the fact that people downvote valid bug reports. Yeah, *this question is not useful* if you're only using English sites, but still ...

Comment: How do you pluralize that word??

Comment: @Shadow in Russian, the grammar is different. Participles are conjungated as well.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard `1 награждение; 2 награждения; 5 награждений` enough?

Comment: Oh. But still, is there any precedence for this, i.e. something without English plurals which got two versions in Transifex?

Comment: I see.. The issue there is that we don't show the actual number (e.g. 1642) when the label on the right says 1.6k... We already implemented the solution for that for view counts (we only pluralize for non-abreviated counts < 1k) on the question page. Will be fixed shortly!

Comment: @m0sa could you please also look at [this report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292880/339911). I think it's related to current one in case of `k`-issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build `2018.1.11.28333`.

Comment: Cool and fast! Thank you very much!

Comment: @alexolut the string key in transifex is [`58f85974b567b37578628981bf79cc27`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/%24/-1?key=58f85974b567b37578628981bf79cc27)

Comment: Looks like the old [string](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266659?key=87e8bcb1c1d6264d54bcbe34371c92b5) is still in use, but for `k` only values. Am I right?

Comment: yes k values have the old value