# “awarded” are not aligned on the badges page for localized sites

Tags: bug, design, badges, localization

After fixing [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305581/339911) different translations of “awarded” word are not aligned vertically in [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) / [Russian language Stack Exchange](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/badges):

> [image: ruso]

Site with English interface like MSE looks fine due to same word length:

> [image: mse]