# Add a new context for "awarded" string to make possible correct translation

Tags: bug, badges, localization

The string ["awarded"](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/5271) is used in two (at least) different contexts:

1. In the [list of site badges](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) for badges that awarded 1k+ times.

> [image: awarded - награждений]

2. In the user profile page on the Activities - [Badges tab](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/?tab=activity&sort=badges):

> [image: awarded - награждён]

The first case is broken now since the correct wording should be "5.4k награждений" (same as for "39 награждений" - the form 'many' of plurals).

It's unable to make different translations if source string wouldn't be split.

Initially the plural versions of "awarded" was added by the answering this question: [Unable to pluralize "awarded" on the badges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305581/339911)